# Any potential problems with having a spring mvc application and jersey in the same project?

Tags: java, spring, jersey, jax-rs

Is there any potential gotchas with having both spring mvc and jersey framework in the same application?

I want the spring to map the '/' while jersey to something like '/service/*'

Other than the urls, I'm more nervious about how I can share hibernate entities/service objects, and also have spring/jersey pick things up with annotations etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shouldn't be a problem. The two servlets (the Spring MVC dispatcher and the Jersey servlet) do not interfere with each other.

However, I would not recommend that. Either use Spring-MVC only, or Jersey only: having both of them is usually unnecessary.

Comment: jersey just seems so much simplier for rest with xml/json outputs.